# Using GADTs with higher order functions

Tags: types, ocaml, higher-order-functions, gadt, locally-abstract-type

I'm trying to model a "heterogeneous tree", ie. a tree where the nodes have different "kinds" and each "kind" are restricted in the "kind" of children they may contain:

```
type id = string
type block
type inline

type _ node =
  | Paragraph : id * inline node list -> block node
  | Strong : id * inline node list -> inline node
  | Text : id * string -> inline node
```

A tree can then be defined like this:

```
let document =
    Paragraph ("p1", [
      Text ("text1", "Hello ");
      Strong ("strong1", [
        Text ("text2", "Glorious")
      ]);
      Text ("text3", " World!")
  ])
```

Usually this would be done using separate variants for each "kind" of node, but I'm trying to define it as a GADT in order to be able to manipulate the tree using higher-order functions that pattern match on every kind of node:

```
function
  | Text ("text2", _) ->
    Some (Text ("text2", "Dreadful"))
  | _ ->
    None
```

The problem I have is in defining the function that accepts the above higher-order function and apply it to every node. So far I have this:

```
let rec replaceNode (type a) (f: a node -> a node option) (node: a node): a node =
  match f node with
  | Some otherNode -> otherNode
  | None ->
    match node with
    | Paragraph (id, children) -> 
      Paragraph (id, (List.map (replaceNode f) children))
    | Strong (id, children) ->
      Strong (id, (List.map (replaceNode f) children))
    | Text (_, _) -> node
```

But the compiler gives me the following error on the highlighted line

> This expression has type block node -> a node option but an expression was expected of type block node -> a node option This instance of block is ambiguous: it would escape the scope of its equation

Or if I change the type of `f` to `'a node -> 'a node option` I get this error instead

> This expression has type a node but an expression was expected of type a node The type constructor a would escape its scope

Clearly I don't fully understand locally abstract types (or GADTs really, for that matter), but from what I do understand these errors seem to arise because the type is, as the name suggests, "local", and while polymorphic on the outside, passing it on would "leak" it, I guess?

So **my question is**, first and foremost: Is this even possible to do (and by "this" I think I mean *to pattern match on a GADT in a higher-order function*, but I'm not even sure that's the actual problem)?

[Playground with all the code here](https://reasonml.github.io/try/?ocaml=C4TwDgpgBAlgJlAvFAzsATjAdgcwFCiRQBGANgPYDGA1geNNqdhHnUQPpRblzSJ5QoAHygAFAIbpxOKWAAWUAFywEAKlhYmWaN15QmaKAFoAfCQo0uPFoJEBlDOVxKVUdY2ZW9B4MbMftLxthKAAVCAAPX2V4N1QMbBw-DS0dawEoPFIIXzgqAFcAWwgsX34ASAkpGXF5KAAKACIwAEZGgBooAG0MwUFwqIbG4EjgNs7GgAkIUgooRoBKAG5evod0JySmtA3cce7VwXKB3yaRqIAmDvmAcQpMcnyURcOoAF1l15Oh8+AAZmujSgAHVyOhSHAAIQvQQfVjZXzoCCUKBIsCkcSUCAAOWsDUI0HECwaADNlOIgskKbpoOQwMAYE5ifUaeSggs2TSkBlCuJgJQFCTKQB3GDAOQZezkYpQcjiiDoXF6Uyy+WK9K2KC4wKmDLlXn8hRc0Xi1YiKrSWQKerwToCmAQpFYYkq14Wmp1G1wTr1AAyMDQADpeWAGmiMVildAScT7Y6SgsFmaoOtNg1bVA43AnS6TK9U84vT7-UGQ2GIOjMTi8THM3IHdmE0m+iFvvV2J12LmgvCclwIML2HlKEUSmU8OVh6PSmazOGq1HSfksJQGU5XiI28NRldO7nXoI7NLoPUt79d-MACJI8RwEn5UiLZstkKcXUvvraiALIA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two root problems here ( which are a bit muddled by the presence of GADTs). The first issue is that `replaceNode` is a second rank polymorphic function. Indeed, in the first match, `f` is applied to a node of type `a node`, but inside the `Paragraph` branch, it is applied to a node of type `inline node`. The type-checker error here is a bit complicated by the `List.map` call, but rewriting the function as

```
let rec replaceNode (type a) (f:a node -> a node option) 
(node:a node): a node =
  match f node with
  | Some otherNode -> otherNode
  | None ->
    match node with
    | Paragraph(id, []) -> Paragraph(id,[])
    | Paragraph (id, a :: children) -> 
      Paragraph (id, f a :: (List.map (replaceNode f) children))
    | Strong (id, children) ->
      Strong (id, (List.map (replaceNode f) children))
    | Text (_, _) -> node;;
```

yields a more straightforward error:

> Error: This expression has type inline node
>   but an expression was expected of type a node
>   Type inline is not compatible with type a

The problem is thus that we need to reassure the type-checker that `f` works for any type `a` and not only the original type `a`. In other words, the type of `f` should be `'a. 'a node -> 'a node option` (aka `forall 'a. 'a -> 'a node option`). Unfortunalety, explicit polymorphic annotation are only possible in first position (prenex) in OCaml, thus we cannot just change the type of `f` in `replaceNode`. However, it is possible to works around this issue by using polymorphic record field or method.

For instance, using the record path, we can define a record type `mapper`:

```
type mapper = { f:'a. 'a node -> 'a node option } [@@unboxed]
```

of which the field `f` has the right explicit polymorphic notation (aka universal quantification) and then use it in `replaceNode`:

```
let rec replaceNode (type a) {f} (node: a node): a node =
  match f node with
  | Some otherNode -> otherNode
  | None ->
    match node with
    | Paragraph (id, children) -> 
      Paragraph (id, (List.map (replaceNode {f}) children))
    | Strong (id, children) ->
      Strong (id, (List.map (replaceNode {f}) children))
    | Text (_, _) -> node
```

But then the second issue pops up: this `replaceNode` function has for type
`mapper -> inline node -> inline node`. Where does the inline type comes from? Ths time the issue is polymorhpic recursion. Without an explicit polymorphic annotation, the type of `replaceNode` is considered constant inside its recursive definition. In other words, the type-checker considers that `replaceNode` has for type `mapper -> 'elt node -> 'elt node` for a *given* `'elt`. And in the `paragraph` and `strong` branchs, the `children` list is a list of `inline node`. Thus `List.map (replaceNode {f}) children` implies for the type-checker that `'elt`=`inline` and thus the type of `replaceNode` becomes `mapper -> inline node -> inline node`.

To fix this issue, we need to add another polymorphic annotation. Fortunately, this time, we can add it directly:

```
let rec replaceNode: type a. mapper -> a node -> a node =
  fun {f} node -> match f node with
  | Some otherNode -> otherNode
  | None ->
    match node with
    | Paragraph (id, children) -> 
      Paragraph (id, (List.map (replaceNode {f}) children))
    | Strong (id, children) ->
      Strong (id, (List.map (replaceNode {f}) children))
    | Text (_, _) -> node;;
```

At last, we obtain a function of type `mapper -> 'a node -> 'a node`.
Note that `let f: type a.…` is a shortcut notation for combining locally abstract type and explicit polymorphic annotation.

Completing the explanation, the locally abstract `(type a)` is needed here because only abstract types can be refined when pattern matching over GADTs. In other words, we need it to precise that the type `a` in the `Paragraph`, `Strong` and `Text` obeys different equalities: `a` = `block` in the Paragraph branch, `a` = `inline` in the `Strong` and `Text` branch.

EDIT: How to define a mapper?

This locally abstract type bit is in fact important when defining a mapper.
For instance, defining

```
let f = function
  | Text ("text2", _) -> Some (Text ("text2", "Dreadful"))
  | _ -> None
```

yields a type `inline node -> inline node option` for `f`, since matching over the constructor `Text` yields the equality `'type_of_scrutinee=inline`.

To correct this point, one need to add a locally abstract type annotation
to make the type-checker able to refine the type of the scrutinee branch-by-branch:

```
 let f (type a) (node:a) : a node option= match node with
 | Text ("text2", _) -> Some (Text ("text2", "Dreadful"))
 | _ -> None
```

Then this f has the right type and can be wrapped inside a mapper record:

```
let f = { f }
```

Advertisement: All this is detailed in the OCaml manual starting at version 4.06 .

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer! The first problem is what I was intuitively trying to solve. The second problem is due to me not properly understanding and distinguishing the syntax for these concepts, and thereby confusing them. Thanks for clearing that up too. There seems to be one piece missing however, how to define the higher-order function? It currently complains that "This field value has type inline node -> inline node option which is less general than 'a. 'a node -> 'a node option" on `{ f = function | ... }`.

Comment: If I bind the function to a variable, I can annotate it with the type `type a. a node -> a node option`, then it works. But is there a more convenient way of doing this for anonymous functions?

Comment: For an anonymous function, using just the locally abtract notation works `(fun (type a) (x:a node): a node option -> match x with …) `. However, the ` fun … : result_type ->` annotation requires OCaml ≥ 4.03.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. I'm of course stuck with 4.02.3 for the time being due to using BuckleScript. So this didn't turn out quite as convenient as I had hoped, but still pretty cool to find out it's possible! Thanks again!

Comment: Note that this only means that you need to wrap the `match` and add a type annotation here:  `fun (type a) (node:a node) -> ((match …) : a node option)` or annotate each branch result invidually